Group close happening events together in ClickHouse
I have ordered table with events, having their time (in ClickHouse table):



time
event




10:30:00
event1


10:30:05
event2


10:30:59
event2


10:31:00
event2


10:31:00
event1



For me, the same events happening in a row are the same.  I need function that will merge these events together. Expected result is:



time
event




10:30:00
event1


10:30:05 (it can be any time from recurring events)
event2


10:31:00
event1




you can use window funtions like so to group the gaps and islands :
with cte as (
select * 
, rank() over (order by time) - rank() over(partition by event order by time) as grp
from EventLog
)

select min(time) as time, event 
from cte 
group by grp, event
order by time 

output:



time
event




10:30:00
event1


10:30:05
event2


10:31:00
event1



you can use max() to get the last time of the same event instead.
